# Unable to move devices outside of current LAN Scope due to IP Conflicts

Tags: networking, ip, switch

We have a few smart Netgear switches that all of our LAN devices plug into.

Currently we are attempting to move a few of these devices into a DMZ on a different Subnet. The DMZ and Lan are setup on a Sonicwall TZ-200.

The LAN is on 192.168.10.X and this DMZ is on 192.168.55.X

Now what we are seeing is that any device moved off the 192.168.10.X network is reporting that it has an IP Conflict. We have attempted to move them to other IPs and Ranges(11.0.x.x) but all of the ones we tested are reporting as conflicts.

I've confirmed that this is all internal and we don't have devices on those ranges.

What I'm I missing here? I've asked around the office and no one has seen this behavior before.

Comment: Did you change the ip address configuration on the affected systems as appropriate for the new subnet?

Comment: We attempted this with a Windows Workstation. Every IP in the subnet 192.168.55.X simply reports as a conflict.

Comment: The IP conflict mechanism is detecting another machine responding to the same IP address. Some other device on the DMZ network, possibly the router itself, is responding to "Who has IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" requests saying "I have IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx." Setup WireShark on an affected machine and watch for ARP requests/responses when you plug in the network cable. You will see the MAC address of whatever machine is responding as having the conflicting IP. Then you find the device with that MAC address by first cross referencing the MAC address  with the hardware vendor.

Comment: Going to load up Wireshark on a device. Its weird, any device that isn't on the 192.168.10.X network reports every other IP as a conflict. I'll check the traffic and comeback with more information.

Answer (score 0):

I examined the network via Wireshark and discovered a 2nd Router that was preforming Proxy ARP.

The feature was removed and we were able to use other IP addresses outside our default LAN.